# Separating 2 elements of a key of a dictionary into 2 lists?

Tags: python

how do i separate the keys of this dict into two separate lists?

```
score = {(13.5, 12.0): 10.5, (10.7, 19.3): 11.4, (12.4, 11.1): 5.3}

list1 = []
list2 = []
```

so that I can have these lists when I print them?

```
list1 = [13.5, 10.7, 12.4]
list2 = [12.0, 19.3, 11.1]
```

i've tried this but it doesn't work

```
for (a, b), x in score:
    list1.append(a,)
    list2.append(b,)
```

Comment: This is the third question today with that same data structure -- the other two from the same user. Are you him as well, or is this a homework question you're both trying to solve?

Comment: @agf haha it's a she. We are in the same Python class, but *coughs* she didn't put too much effort on this I think? We've never talked to each other, but looking at her questions, she didn't even put up any codes that she has attempted in her questions... I think this site is more of a way to help you to troubleshoot problems on what you already have, but she seems like asking for solutions without even trying. Come on.

Comment: *hopes that she wont see this*

Comment: @agf what does the homework tag do? :s

Comment: It lets people know not to post a complete solution to what could be an entire homework assignment. With a specific question like this, people probably wouldn't answer any differently.

Comment: oh i didn't know about that! i'm pretty new here so yeah thanks, will use the tag in my future questions :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, just remove the `, x`.

Iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys, not its keys and values. Since you only need the keys here, iterating over the dictionary is fine.

Alternatively, you could iterate over `score.items()` instead (or `score.iteritems()` only on Python 2).

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the keys of the dictionary, but assigning to `(key, value)`. To iterate over the key-value pairs you can use `items` or `iteritems`:

```
for (a, b), x in score.iteritems():
```

In this specific case you could use list comprehensions instead of an explicit loop:

```
list1 = [a for a, b in score]
list2 = [b for a, b in score]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you can use a combination of zip and splat (the unpack)

```
>>> score = {(13.5, 12.0): 10.5, (10.7, 19.3): 11.4, (12.4, 11.1): 5.3}
>>> x, y = zip(*score.keys())
>>> x
(10.7, 12.4, 13.5)
>>> y
(19.3, 11.1, 12.0)
```

Comment: The `.keys` is unnecessary (though OK if you want to be explicit). If you're going to rewrite the code I think this is the way to go, though it's a bit tricky for a beginner.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. I always forget that iterating over dict yields keys by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly loop over your keys

```
for (a, b) in score.keys():
    list1.append(a)
    list2.append(b)
```

Comment: It defaults to that, right -- but newcomers usually don't know and hence using .keys() reminds them of what they are actually accessing ;)